# Getting in the arms or Getting on the arms?

Tags: prepositions

This is not about getting a hug. It is about
picking up the baby and holding her in/on the arms.

What's the correct usage?

Comment: You can pick the baby up with your arms, and you can hold the baby in your arms. But if you hold the baby on your arms, you better be careful the baby doesn't fall off. And I'd think that would be difficult to do, to hold a baby on your arms. Go ahead and try it, if you can find a mother who'll let you try that kind of experiment with her baby.

Comment: @F.E.: Well, *all* mothers *I* know (me included) have placed their baby *on* their arm(s) at times, for example when they were gassy or curious. This position is common enough to even have a name:" (reverse) football hold" (not to be confused with the breastfeeding position) and if done right, no baby will fall off. Also, most mothers place their small babies *on* their lower arms to hold them in a slightly raised position for face-to-face interaction.

Comment: @Stephie Ah, so context might be important here. Perhaps you could add that extra info into your answer post, with those examples which show the uses with "on" in them. :)

Comment: @Stephie and F.E. I think it could be better if the OP edited the question to make it clear whose arms we are talking about anyway: the baby's or the dad's (or mom's). (I have a hunch that some other words than *in* or *on* would be a better fit.)

Answer (score 1):

Both are ok.

- *on* the arms
  focuses on the supporting function of your arms, like *arms below, baby on top* while
- *in* the arms
  points out the encompassing, hugging, even protecting  aspect.

Just for fun: Do an image search on the web for "baby hold on arms" and "baby hold in arms" - basically the same pictures...

Comment: Thanks, I think I am worrying too much about my English.

Comment: *Do an image search on the web for "baby hold on arms" and "baby hold in arms"* -- so I tried. I also checked out the Google image search results of `baby hold on arms` to see the text, and found that most of the time it's "in arms" or it's only about "baby" not really about "arms" (I wonder how much Google would care about *in* or *on* in such a search), and when I found "on" close to "arms", it usually is about the baby's arms, not the arms of someone who's holding the baby. This [Google Ngram search](https://goo.gl/LhpsFM) also suggests the opposite of "basically the same", imho.

Comment: @DamkerngT.: Well, Google "works in mysterious ways", often enough results will depend on where you are searching *from* and occasionally even vary depending on your browser history - feel free to post your own answer if you disagree with mine. Also remember that OP asks specifically for babies. With children, "in" and "on" would be slightly different, "in" not necessarily implying "lift up".